# 23.10 Kubuntu, system freezes, how do I troubleshoot this?

Tags: kubuntu

Updated from 23.04 to 10.  Now the system is freezing in a non-predictable way, intermittently.

complete freeze of the display.

How do I begin to troubleshoot this?  How can I filter journalctl in a meaningful way?

What other troubleshooting steps are there?

Answer (score 1):

System "freezes" are often caused by running too many, too large programs and running out of available memory. Use `free` to see if you have swap space, read `man mkswap swapon fstab fallocate` to create some. Swap space must be contiguous. use `mkswap` or `fallocate`, not `dd`. Traditionally, swap space of 1.5 × RAM has been recommended,  but YMMV. If you don't plan to hibernate your system, you can have less than 1.0 × RAM.

You can use `sudo journalctl  -b 0` and `sudo journalctl  --since="-10 minutes"` (for various values of "10") to look at logs. Read `man journalctl`, look in my AskUbuntu profile (click my user name) for more `journalctl` help.

Comment: thank you, I asked a better version of this question here:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1492796/how-can-i-further-diagnose-a-freezing-problem-error-crtc131pipe-b-which-h 

I'm thinking it has something to do with display.  As so far it only happens when plugged into my second monitor.