# How can I further diagnose a freezing problem, Error: [CRTC:131:pipe B], which happend after upgrading to 23.10?

Tags: 23.10

```
Nov 15 11:23:08 laptop-txtechnician rtkit-daemon[1663]: Supervising 9 threads of 6 processes of 1 users.
Nov 15 11:23:08 laptop-txtechnician rtkit-daemon[1663]: Supervising 9 threads of 6 processes of 1 users.
Nov 15 11:23:25 laptop-txtechnician kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* flip_done timed out
Nov 15 11:23:25 laptop-txtechnician kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* [CRTC:131:pipe B] commit wait timed out
Nov 15 11:23:30 laptop-txtechnician dbus-daemon[878]: [system] Activating service name='org.kde.powerdevil.backlighthelper' requested by ':1.253' (uid=1000 pid=3517 comm="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/org_kde_powerdev" label="unconfined") (using servicehelper)
Nov 15 11:23:30 laptop-txtechnician dbus-daemon[878]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.kde.powerdevil.backlighthelper'
Nov 15 11:23:39 laptop-txtechnician kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* [CRTC:131:pipe B] flip_done timed out
Nov 15 11:23:50 laptop-txtechnician kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* flip_done timed out
Nov 15 11:23:50 laptop-txtechnician kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* [CRTC:131:pipe B] commit wait timed out
-- Boot 04ac6fe86a3d4dbf80048869961c6282 --
```

so far this has only happened to me while having my second monitor plugged in.

It happens so infrequently that I'm having trouble reproducing the problem.

System Info:

```
Operating System: Kubuntu 23.10
KDE Plasma Version: 5.27.8
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.110.0
Qt Version: 5.15.10
Kernel Version: 6.5.0-10-generic (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 20 × 13th Gen Intel® Core™ i9-13900H
Memory: 15.2 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: Mesa Intel® Graphics
Manufacturer: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
Product Name: Vivobook_ASUSLaptop TP3604VA_TP3604VA
System Version: 1.0
```

Comment: Did you get to solve this? It seems to be a problem with the integrated card's driver. Intel i915. In kubuntu 22.x.x this isue is not present. See:https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=286419

Comment: I've got the same error, but only when a second monitor is plugged.

(linuxMint 21.3 Cinnamon 6.0.4 with kernel "Linux ubuntu-NS5x-NS7xAU 6.5.0-1011-oem #12-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Jan 3 20:17:42 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux")

Answer (score 1):

I' found this discussion for inspiration : https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/intel/-/issues/8685

I tried to boot with Kernel parameter `i915.dmc_firmware_path=` and for now, with a second monitor plugged, my computer did not freeze.

I don't know what this parameter do, but it save my worker life at the moment :-)

Comment: Yeah it is a kernel error related to the intel driver. It has been fixed up to kernel version `6.7.x`. I recommend you to update if you can. FYI: https://9to5linux.com/you-can-now-install-linux-kernel-6-7-on-ubuntu-heres-how