# My laptop freezes when connecting external monitor via DP or HDMI

Tags: kernel, 22.04, dell, freeze, monitor

I have a new DELL 7440 laptop with Ubuntu 22.04.03 and I'm using Xorg instead of Wayland. When I connect an external monitor, via Display Port from docking station Dell WD19TB or directly using HDMI cable, after a while the laptop freezes. I'm still able to move the "pointer" but the system becomes unusable and must be switched off. This doesn't happen when using the laptop without connecting the external monitor.

I found the hereafter messages on the syslog file:

```
Jan 14 11:42:41 grossi-Latitude-7440 kernel: [ 2827.331368] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* flip_done timed out
Jan 14 11:42:41 grossi-Latitude-7440 kernel: [ 2827.331377] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* [PLANE:82:plane 1B] commit wait timed out
Jan 14 11:42:51 grossi-Latitude-7440 kernel: [ 2837.571179] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* [CRTC:131:pipe B] flip_done timed out
Jan 14 11:43:01 grossi-Latitude-7440 kernel: [ 2847.810994] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* flip_done timed out
Jan 14 11:43:01 grossi-Latitude-7440 kernel: [ 2847.811004] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* [CRTC:131:pipe B] commit wait timed out
Jan 14 11:43:11 grossi-Latitude-7440 kernel: [ 2858.050798] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* flip_done timed out
Jan 14 11:43:11 grossi-Latitude-7440 kernel: [ 2858.050809] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* [CONNECTOR:272:DP-3] commit wait timed out
```

I did a quick search and I guess it could be a kernel bug. Can someone confirm it and point me to the specific bug, so I can be notified when it will be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Same for me, I use a Samsung Book2, Ubuntu 22.04.3, kernel 6.5.0-14-generic and wayland. I use two screens, one of them freezes and the other doesn't.

```
jan 19 08:18:07 book2 kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0:
[drm] *ERROR* [CRTC:131:pipe B] flip_done timed out
```

If you wait, it returns to normal in around 20 minutes.
If you lock (Ctrl + Alt + Shift + L) and wait a few seconds it also returns to normal.

Answer (score 0):

For those interested, folks over at [archlinux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1500411/my-laptop-freezes-when-connecting-external-monitor-via-dp-or-hdmi) seem to have pinpointed it to a vsync issue. The problem seems to have popped up for me since the 6.x kernels. I am running a laptop with intel 12700H and Nvidia GTX1650 on 22.04, upgrading to the 525 driver did not seem to matter.

The page [1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1500411/my-laptop-freezes-when-connecting-external-monitor-via-dp-or-hdmi) refers to [freedesktop](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/intel/-/issues/8685) which allowed me to find a solution on [in another answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1492796/how-can-i-further-diagnose-a-freezing-problem-error-crtc131pipe-b-which-h). I am going to have a try at (first the 6.7 kernel than; 6.7 is not available for 22.04) the boot parameter. Will be back once results are in.

Answer (score 0):

Following on @Jeroen's comments, I've been dealing with the same issue for a week now. The boot parameter mentioned in the previous comments as well as on https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/intel/-/issues/8685 seemed to work (had no crashes for the past couple days) but it has returned.

On that same gitlab there's a comment from a month ago saying it's already been patched on v6.7, so it seems changing kernel version is the only viable route atm, but 6.7 isn't available yet as on 22.04 as far as I could check.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `i915.dmc_firmware_path=` in GRUB have worked for me (Ubuntu 22.04.4, 6.5.0-21-generic).

```bash
# Edit grub and add `i915.dmc_firmware_path=` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`.
vi /etc/default/grub

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="i915.dmc_firmware_path= quiet splash"
```

Save and update grub

```bash
update-grub
```